# as3 Video not displayed on PC in debug mode

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, video

I am developing an app in as3+AIR for iPad with Flashdevelop.
I stream a flv with StageVideo and everything is working fine deployed on iPad.
But on the PC in Flashdevelop Debug mode no video is shown, although it gets played (NET_STATUS events are dispatched).
Any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 1):

According to Adobe's [Flash Roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html), StageVideo won't be supported on PCs until 2013.

Try adding some code which checks for StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY:

```
function onStageVideoState(e:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void
{
    var available:Boolean = (e.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE);
    trace("Got StageVideo?", available);
}

stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoState);
```

When StageVideo is not available, you'll have to use a regular Video object as a fallback.